# Ruby on Rails Views. (Best Practice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might seem like a strange question. But have been pondering over this for quite some time now.

> Is it better to use RAW HTML in Rails views or to go with Rails view helpers??

If i understand correctly Rails views helpers are converted back to raw HTML. So would it affect the performance of the application by a great deal ??

And is there a tool that would allow me to convert HTML to ERB :)

I'm aware of the HTML to HAML converter.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly better to use a rails helper, as this allows you to create dynamic elements

Comment: Uncluttered views yes. But could you elaborate on the "dynamic elements" part a little ??

Comment: Sure! I specifically meant the "image_tag" & "asset_url" helpers when I mentioned the dynamic elements. The reason being that if the core Rails structure changes, these will still point to the correct media

Comment: thank you :) will definitely have a detailed look at that, till now was using HTML in views.

Answer (score 0):

Use Rails helpers, they guarantee the latest HTML good practice are used and up to date.